# Regex - filter with (1) hyphen or (2) end of sentence

Tags: r, regex, filtering

I need support with RegEx filtering!

I have a list of keywords and many rows that should be checked.
In this example, the keyword "-book-" can be (1) in the middle of the sentence or (2) at the end, which would mean that the last hyphen is not present.

I need a RegEx expression, which identifies "-book-" and "-book".
I don't want similar keywords like "-booking-" etc to be identified.

```
library(dplyr)
keywords = c( "-album-",  "-book-", "-castle-")                 
search_terms = paste(keywords, collapse ="|")                
number = c(1:5)
sentences = c("the-best-album-in-shop", "this-book-is-fantastic", "that-is-the-best-book", "spacespacespace", "unwanted-sentence-with-booking")   
data = data.frame(number, sentences)
```

```
output = data %>% filter(., grepl( search_terms, sentences) )
```

```
# Current output:
 number              sentences
1      1 the-best-album-in-shop
2      2 this-book-is-fantastic
```

```
# DESIRED output:
  number              sentences
1      1 the-best-album-in-shop
2      2 this-book-is-fantastic
3      3  that-is-the-best-book
```

Comment: Remove `"-book-"`, add `"\\bbook-", "-book\\b"` to `search_terms`

Comment: Thanks that worked for this small example.. But in my full list with keywords it gave errors. Keywords starting with "W" or "S" gave errors, as \\W is the command for Non-word characters and \\S also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also do:

```
subset(data, grepl(paste0(sprintf("%s?\\b",keywords),collapse = "|"), sentences))

  number              sentences
1      1 the-best-album-in-shop
2      2 this-book-is-fantastic
3      3  that-is-the-best-book
```

Note that this will only check for the `-book-` at the *(1) in the middle of the sentence or (2) at the end* Not at the beginning

Answer (score 1):

The `-book-` pattern will match a whole word `book` with hyphen on the left *and* right.

To match a whole word `book` with a hyphen on the left *or* right, you need an alternation `\bbook-|-book\b`.

Thus, you can use

```
keywords = c( "-album-",  "\\bbook-", "-book\\b", "-castle-" )
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution you can take it into account

```
library(stringr)
data %>% 
  filter(str_detect(sentences, regex("-castle-|-album-|-book$|-book-\\w{1,}")))
#   number              sentences
# 1      1 the-best-album-in-shop
# 2      2 this-book-is-fantastic
# 3      3  that-is-the-best-book
```